# Check if string matches array key format

Tags: php, regex

I am currently working on a custom URL routing script for our website. We would like to define URL patterns as array keys, and check if the specified URL matches one of these keys in format.

For example, we have an array defined as follows:

```
$rewrites = array(
    'item[0-9].html' => array('target' => 'http://example.com')
);
```

We would like to retrieve the array for `$rewrites['item[0-9].html']` when the URL is `item1.html`, something like:

```
function get_info( $url )
{
    // $url = 'item1.html';
    // return value for $rewrites['item[0-9].html']
}
```

How can we check to see if the array key exists and retrieve its value by passing `item1.html` to a function? I am concerned that looping through the entire array (which will hold ~ 200 items) and performing a `preg_match()` on the key will be slow. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no way around testing all those expressions one by one with your approach. Consider moving this logic to the level of the http server where the regex engine is _much_ more efficient.

Comment: Also, you *will* run into problems in the future, when your keys get to complex. Just check out htaccess redirects :)

Comment: Otherwise consider splitting this up into a multi step approach: instead of applying each full pattern one by one until you find a match (or not) consider using "prefix patterns" (`^item`) in this example, _if_ you have multiple patterns starting with the same prefix for example. Only if a prefix matches you proceed to step two and test further staying with that prefix. That _might_ drastical reduce the total number of patterns you have to test depending on the structure of your pattern set.

Comment: Read about `Routing` and try to use URLs like `/item/1` or `/item/1.html` to make the work easier. You then can match `item` directly, no use of regex needed.

Comment: You can also do a pre check with `strpos($URL,'item')===0` and then do all `item[REGEX].html` that you have. Then not all 200 rewrites will be tested, only the one that are relevant.  New structure `$rewrites['item']['item[0-9]+\.html']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO 200 requests are not that much, specially if you are using PHP7.0~, so I suggest to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), and using the named patterns this will help you which pattern has fetched the result, but with this approach, you might have one URL matched against multiple patterns.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param string $url
 * @param array  $rewrites
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_info(string $url, array $rewrites): array
{
    $patterns = [
        'original' => [],
        'named' => [],
    ];
    foreach (array_keys($rewrites) as $key => $pattern) {
        $index = "pattern_{$key}";
        $patterns ['original'][$index] = $pattern;
        $patterns ['named'][$index] = "(?P<{$index}>{$pattern})";
    }

    $patternsString = '#(' . implode('|', $patterns['named']) . ')#';

    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all($patternsString, $url, $matches);

    $matchedPatterns = [];
    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
            if (key_exists($key, $patterns['named']) 
                && count($match) > 0
                && !empty($match[0])) {
                $matchedPatterns [] = $rewrites[$patterns['original'][$key]];
            }
        }
    }

    return $matchedPatterns;
}

$rewrites = [
    'item[0-9].html' => ['target' => 'http://example.com'],
    '-item.html' => ['target' => 'http://example1.com'],
];

$testData = [
    'item1.html' => [['target' => 'http://example.com']],
    '-item.html' => [['target' => 'http://example1.com']],
];   

foreach ($testData as $key => $datum) {
    $output = get_info($key, $rewrites);
    assert($datum == $output, sprintf("\"%s\" has wrong matches.", $key));
}
```

Can be tested [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53e9738091a99d02d5266c0c1ef270f031051151)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($rewrites as $key => $row) {
    preg_match_all('/item\d\.html/', $key, $matches);

    if (isset($matches[0][0])) {
        echo $matches[0][0];
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.